# Flutter/Dart - Navigator.pop(context) stopped working after adding BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, future

Page One in my stack has a `BottomNavigationBar`.
The first tab calls a `FutureBuilder` which returns a `PageView.builder`.
Swiping it navigates to Page Two.

Previously, clicking `Navigator.pop(context)` in Page Two brought me back to Page One. But since adding a BottomNavigationBar to Page Two, the button no longer pops back. Instead, I get a black screen.

Why would adding a `BottomNavigationBar` to Page Two stop it popping back to Page One?

Curiously, using the regular Android back button on my phone DOES work. Shouldn't using `Navigator.pop(context)` be the same as using the back button on an Android phone? If not how can I get my button to behave the same as Android's back button?

Here's the code for Page Two;

```
class HomeReply extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeReplyState createState() => new _HomeReplyState();
}

class _HomeReplyState extends State<HomeReply> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  static List<Widget> _myPages = <Widget>[
    ReplyStage(),
    Account(),
  ];
  
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var socialProvider = Provider.of<SocialProvider>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([socialProvider.loadCurrentName(), socialProvider.loadCurrentAvatar()]),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Back to "Original Post",
            ),

          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,             
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ),
        body: _myPages[_selectedIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
              ),
              title: Text('Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Consumer<SocialProvider>(
                  builder: (context, socialProvider, child) {
                    return Image.network(snapshot.data[1],
                    );
                  }),
              title: Consumer<SocialProvider>(
                  builder: (context, socialProvider, child) {
                    return Text(snapshot.data[0]);
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
         ),
      );
    } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else{
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem wasn't the `BottomNavigationBar` after all. The problem was a duplicated `MaterialApp` here at:

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder
```

Once I changed this to `return FutureBuilder` the `Navigator.pop(context)` went back to working as normal.